# Using the ImportXML googlesheets function, can I reference a cell within my xpath query argument?

Tags: xml, xpath, geonames, google-sheets

I have a list of geocoded places, but I need to find the best match in a different gazetteer (Geonames). I'm attempting to use the FindNearby api from Geonames (http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearby) to get a list of nearby places and then use an xpath query to identify nodes (and siblings of nodes) that contain the correct placename and corresponding id.

In my Google spreadsheet I have three columns (and several hundred rows):

```
*placename, latitude, longitude*

*Sher-e-bangla Nagar, 23.7658, 90.37719*

*Shapahar, 25.1259, 88.58793*

...
```

In a fourth column, I want to use ImportXML to retrieve a concatenated list of node values:

```
=JOIN(",",Importxml(CONCATENATE("http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=",B2,"&lng=",C2,"&localCountry=true&radius=50&maxRows=100&username=demo"),"/geonames/geoname/toponymName[starts-with(.,'**Sher**')] |/geonames/geoname/toponymName[starts-with(.,'**Sher**')]/following-siblings::geonameId"))
```

This works and returns "Sher-e-bangla Nagor,7697516". But Instead of using "**Sher**" in my expression, is there a way to reference cell A2 within the xpath query? This would allow me to carry it through all rows and point the expression to the correct placenames. Ideally I'd want to use left(A2, 4) to search ToponymName nodes that match the first four letters of cells in column A.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenate on the xpath, just like you used on the url string:

```
concatenate("/geonames/geoname/toponymName[starts-with(.,'",A2,"')]|/geonames/geoname/toponymName[starts-with(.,'",A2,"')]/following-siblings::geonameId")
```